# Magento 1.x sites (live and staging on different cPanel accounts) suddenly gives Fatal Error

Tags: magento-1, fatal-error

Both my Magento sites hosted on different cPanel accounts started giving the following error.

`[05-May-2020 08:42:52 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Exception' with message 'Unknown date format, neither date nor time in 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' found' in /home/abceutop/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:1357`

Update:

Futher investigation. This error was found in /var/report

````
#1 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(270): Zend_Currency->toCurrency(0, Array)
#2 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(242): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->formatTxt(NULL, Array)
#3 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(222): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->formatPrecision(NULL, 2, Array, true, false)
#4 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Bar.php(82): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->format(NULL)
#5 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Bar.php(62): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Bar->format(NULL)
#6 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Totals.php(74): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Bar->addTotal('Revenue', NULL)
#7 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(297): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Totals->_prepareLayout()
#8 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#9 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard.php(50): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...')
#10 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(297): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard->_prepareLayout()
#11 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#12 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
#13 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/dashb...', 'dashboard')
#14 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#15 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#16 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#17 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#18 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#19 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php(40): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#20 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_DashboardController->indexAction()
#21 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#22 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#23 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#24 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#25 /home/goeduco/abcdefgijk.ab-cde.fg.hi/shop/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#26 {main}";s:3:"url";s:75:"/shop/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/342a221207039e473fa1014dc6c90f68/";s:11:"script_name";s:15:"/shop/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}```

Nothing has changed as far as I know.
````

Comment: in lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php i just replace iconv_strpos to strpos and it works for me. You can try it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unknown date format, neither date nor time in 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' found Magento1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312025/unknown-date-format-neither-date-nor-time-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-found-magent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's related to the latest ALT-PHP packages updates from CloudLinux. mostly, your hoster is running cPanel with CloudLinux Select PHP tool. contact your provider and ask to update packages from root - https://blog.cloudlinux.com/alt-php-updated-1588679259515

Answer (score 0):

Noticed this problem on the 5/5/2020. The only quick fix i have managed to find so far is to replace iconv_strpos wtih mb_strpos of all instances in lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php as mentioned in this post

[Unknown date format, neither date nor time in 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' found Magento1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312025/unknown-date-format-neither-date-nor-time-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-found-magent)